# interpreting backtrace error message

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When I compile my code using gfortran -g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=invalid,overflow,underflow File.f90 I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE : Floating - Point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:

#0 0x7f3da0768ed7 in ???
#1 0x7f3da076810d in ???
#2 0x7f3d9fe9b7ef in ???
#3 0x7f3da0230a3e in ???
```

My question is: how can I interpret these numbers and ???'s under "backtrace for this error:".  How can I use this error message to help me find the error?  Are they somehow related to the specific lines of code that are problematic? If so, how?

As of now I realize I have an erroneous arithmetic operation error but I have no idea where and this backtrace error message doesn't help at all.  If I compile using just gfortran File.f90, there are no error messages at all during compilation or during running.

Comment: I don't know fortran, but when I've run into bizarre messages like this in other languages where it isn't clear where the error is happening, I'll sprinkle `print` statements all over the place and see what the last one to print was. It's usually the best way to narrow your scope down in the absence of a useful location. A debugger would be a good option too if it's available.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have done that.  Thank you!

Comment: When debugging, I usually disable optimisation (`-O0`), that makes it easier to see where things go wrong.

Comment: @chw21 thanks for the suggestion I just added that and still the same error messages. Do you know how I can interpret the current error messages I'm getting?

Comment: Try using the command `addr2line` on some of those adresses. You might have some luck with that.

Comment: @RussF what addresses? How do I use that command? Where do I put the command? I've never done so before, thanks! Let me know I'll do so ASAP.

Comment: @RussF I added that command you suggested before ./a.out and the result I got was "??:0"what does this mean?

Comment: `man addr2line`!   Something like `addr2line -e a.out 0x7f3da0768ed7 0x7f3da076810d ` etc.

Comment: @RussF  thanks the result I get from that is "??:0". How can I interpret this?

Comment: From the manpage: `If the file name or function name can not be determined, addr2line will print two question marks in their place.  If the
       line number can not be determined, addr2line will print 0.`. Note that an underflow could well be harmless or handled with a compiler switch. Do you have a problem if the check for underflow is removed?

Comment: @RussF I just removed underflow and the code now runs fine, no error messages . What's going on? Are there bugs or, what's the underflow error exactly?

Comment: Before catching this problem, I just compiled using gfortran File.f90 and ./a.out , my code compiled and ran fine however eventually stopped after hours due to an underflow warning error. Then I added all the flags and such and now I'm here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might depend on which target you're using. The GFortran backtrace functionality depends on libbacktrace, which might not work on all targets. On Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 for the code

```
program bt
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  real(real64) :: a, b = -1
  a = sqrt(b)
  print *, a
end program bt
```

when compiling with

```
gfortran -g -ffpe-trap=invalid  bt.f90
```

I get

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F08C38E8E08
#1  0x7F08C38E7F90
#2  0x7F08C35384AF
#3  0x4007F9 in MAIN__ at bt.f90:5
zsh: floating point exception  ./a.out
```

where on stack frame #3 you can see that the error occurs on line 5 in bt.f90.

Now, what are the stuff on stack frames #0-#2? Well, they are the backtracing functionality in libgfortran, the GFortran runtime library. libbacktrace for one reason or another cannot resolve symbols in a dynamic library. If I link it statically:

```
gfortran -g -static -ffpe-trap=invalid  bt.f90
```

I get

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x40139E in _gfortrani_backtrace
#1  0x400D00 in _gfortrani_backtrace_handler
#2  0x439B2F in gsignal
#3  0x400C01 in MAIN__ at bt.f90:5
zsh: floating point exception  ./a.out
```

Comment: Thanks for a lot the answer and simple code to explain everything. I have two questions/clarifications. This may seem obvious but I just want to clarify, the problem with the sample code you provide is that you defined a as real, but then use a=sqrt(-1), so a is not real.  Thus we are getting this erroneous arithmetic operation. Correct?  Secondly:  if I compile using just 'trap=invalid' I get no error messages at all, then run the code and all is fine. but if I use 'trap=invalid',underflow ; I get error messages.  How come removing underflow from 'trap' changes everything?

Comment: @JeffFaraci b is a real, so sqrt(b) is also real. Initializing b from an integer literal doesn't convert b to an integer, instead the integer value is converted to a real when it is assigned to a real variable. I was using only fpe-trap=invalid since that is sufficient to trap the sqrt() of a negative number in my example; since I haven't seen your code I have no idea which exception causes the trap there.